# Maintain java object state when calling java process from bash script

Tags: java, bash

```
    public class Go {
            private static SomeObject fld;
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                   //depending on the args I do call different methods(among 
                   //them one arg will do the job of initialization of fld variable)
            }
    }
```

I call the above java function from the bash script.

```
while true
do
    read commands
    java -cp some-jar.jar Go <commands>
then
```

Say command1 does initialization of **fld** in the **Go** class and command2 does some processing over the initialized field.

As I am calling different java processes for the different commands the objects **fld** state is not getting persisted for the next command.

How can I modify the code such that the **fld** information gets persisted for the next commands without using some database or deserializing and serializing?

Comment: every invocation of java is a clean slate - unless you store state to a file or something before you exit main

Comment: Have you considered iterating all of the commands with bash, building a single (large) list of commands and then passing those commands once to java? **Or**, just reading `commands` with Java to begin with?

Comment: you are saying it like don't use the features that are actually provided to serve the purpose of persisting state of an object. Why are you looking up for other alternative than serialization and deserialization?

Comment: I need to give a response to every individual command. Here I am taking input from the interactive shell.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the first java process alive just like I am keeping the bash process alive? @VinayPrajapati

Comment: Well! you are talking about persisting the object state for next commands. you are kind of mixing OS processes with Java.  Anyways Java process can be kept alive if you can use multi-threading but again mixing up bash commands with java processes is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could store result in bash variable:

**Go.java**:

```
class Go {
    private static String fld;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fld = args[0];
        fld += fld.length();
        System.out.println(fld);
    }
}
```

**run.sh**

```
VALUE=test

while true
do
    VALUE=`java  Go $VALUE`
    echo $VALUE
done
```

**Output**:

```
test4
test45
test456
test4567
test45678
```

Or store result into file, read it in bash and pass as parameter into Go.java .

Here is file storage example:

***File example Go.java***:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

class Go {
    private static String fld;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        fld = args[0];
        fld += fld.length();
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("store.txt");
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
        printWriter.print(fld);
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

**File example run.sh**:

```
VALUE=store
while true
do

    java  Go $VALUE
    VALUE=`cat ./store.txt`
    echo $VALUE
done
```

**File example Output**:

```
store5
store56
store567
store5678
```

Comment: It works if `fld` is a string. How could I achieve it, if `fld` is an instance of some java class?

Comment: I would consider two approaches: 
1) jackson `ObjectMapper` and serialize to json 

2) If this class implements Serializable then serialize it into base64 string through `ObjectOutputStream` and `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString` . I could create an sample if you need it.